# How to properly reconnect via SSH after screen detached

Tags: python, django, linux

I'm working on a Django project that is hosted in a remote server, and in my work we connect through a computer which has Mobaxterm. The thing is, I'm not at all experienced, and the connection broke (or I broke it, I don't know), and then I wrote `screen -r -d`  which is what I used to use to make the `git pull`  and then the `supervisorctl restart`  just to apply the changes I did on my local project.

After the disconnection, it said there were no screens to detach, so after searching online, I managed to get into a screen, and then made my way to the correct path so that I could do `python manage.py etc...`, and I activated the virtualenv.

The thing is, I'm having errors I didn't have, so I don't know if I have to do something else. For example, when I try to do `python manage.py showmigrations` , I get an error saying:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/webapps/project_name/app_name/logs/dialogflow.log'
```

And different errors occur when I do `python manage.py makemigrations` , `python manage.py migrate`, etc. What could the last screen I was working on had and not this one? My ex-coworker, who set everything up before I arrived, hasn't answered, or I'd like at least a clue about how to troubleshoot this, because I'm lost.

Any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A co-worker helped me via remote, and we got the problem. I had to also run `postactivate` from the virtualenv, after the `activate`.